# Trying to derive the Laurent Expansion of $\wp$ (Weierstrass Elliptic function)

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

I have the definition of the Weierstrass elliptical function $\wp$ as:
$$\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\neq 0}\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}$$

Where $w=n\omega_1+m\omega_2$, for $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ the periods of $\wp$.

Also I have the definition for the anti-derivative of $\wp$, $\zeta$. We have $\zeta'(z)=-\wp(z)$ with $$\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{\omega\neq0}\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}$$

In order to find the laurent expansion of $\wp$ I am trying to find the laurent expansion of $\zeta$ and then differentiating termwise as $\zeta$ and $\wp$ converge uniformly. Beginning:

$$\frac{1}{z-\omega}=\frac{-1}{\omega(1-\frac{z}{\omega})}=\frac{-1}{\omega}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{w^n}$$ and so $$\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}=-\frac{z^2}{\omega^3}-\frac{z^3}{\omega^4}$$ And now I am stuck. In Ahlfors complex analysis text Chapter $7$, Section $3.3$ he observes that when we sum over all the periods the terms with odd powers of the periods are zero (equivalently the even powers of $z$). I can't follow this step. I know it must be true as $\zeta$ is an odd function. However why can we jump to this conclusion?

Comment: Why not just expand out $1/(z-\omega)^2$ in a power series?

Comment: Ah yes of course that would work. However the power series would have odd powers of $z$ which are not present in the laurent expansion of $\wp$. How do those powers disappear?

Comment: Well the next step would be to interchange sums, and the odd powers will likely disappear at that point.

Comment: I don't understand how the powers disappear. This is the same problem that I stated above but now for $\wp$ rather than $\zeta$. Would you be able to give a full answer if possible?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to work it out

Answer (score 5):

$$ \wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\neq 0}\Big[\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\Big]=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\neq 0}\Big[\frac{1}{\omega^2}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{z}{\omega})^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\Big] $$

$$=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\neq 0}\frac{1}{\omega^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(m+1)\Big(\frac{z}{\omega}\Big)^{m}=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\Big[\sum_{\omega\neq 0}\frac{m+1}{\omega^{m+2}}\Big]z^m$$

using the fact that
$$ -1+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(m+1)x^m $$
for $|x|<1$, and using the absolute convergence of the $\wp$ function to interchange the sums.

Finally, if $m$ is odd then $\omega^{m+2}=-(-\omega)^{m+2}$, hence 
$$ \sum_{\omega\neq 0}\frac{m+1}{\omega^{m+2}}=0 $$
because for every non-zero element $\omega$ there is a corresponding term $-\omega$ in the sum. This shows that all the odd powers vanish in the Laurent expansion.